How to Make NVDA Screen Reader Announce Different Text than Displayed Text in React
I'm working on a React application where I'm using the Label component from @fluentui/react. I need the NVDA screen reader to announce different text than the one displayed on the screen.
For example, I have a label that displays "Username", but I want NVDA to announce "Enter your username".
How can I achieve this? Is there a way to set an accessible name or use aria-label to override the displayed text for screen readers like NVDA?
Here's a sample of my code:
import React from 'react';
import { Label } from '@fluentui/react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Label aria-label="Enter your username">Username</Label>
      <input type="text" id="username" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;


Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
I already tried the aria-label, aria-labelledby and many aria tags but no one is working. I also tried to hide the text but hidden text is not not readable by NVDA

NVDA only announces the aria-label if the element containing that attribute is empty. To achieve that you must hide the content from screen readers. You can do that by wrapping the content inside a span and then adding aria-hidden="true" to that element:
<div>
  <Label aria-label="Enter your username"><span aria-hidden="true">Username</span></Label>
  <input type="text" id="username" />
</div>

